# Resizing several elements to a specific value on their own position at once.

Tags: adobe-indesign

In *or* for InDesign I am looking for a tool *or* script to resize several boxes at once, but: they should resize separately on their own reference point (which is set in the Transform panel/Control panel for the transformation) and not altogether.

Thanks in advance!
Regards, Serkan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select an object, resize it.
Select all other objects, then run Object > Transform again > Transform again sequence individually.
Et voilà...

Answer (score 1):

As vinny said there is an option for this. While it repeats last transform only, If you have two changes, one for width and one for length, do it twice! So don't forget to add a shortcut key for it if you have to do it alot!
edit > keyboard shortcuts > Product area: Object menu > Commands: > Transform again: Transform again individually

- In "New shortcut" field hold or press keyboard key you want to use for that.
  ** Beware of warnings if shortcut already applied to one of your favorite commands.